# Still seeing the old version of typescript after installing the latest one

Tags: typescript, npm-install

I would like to update the typescipt version on my local computer.

My current version is 0.9.7.0 result of `tsc -v`

What I did:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
npm install typescript@latest
```

Now if I do `npm list -g` I can see a tree with (somewhere in the tree) `typescript@3.2.2`

But if I do `tsc -v` I still see `0.9.7.0`

What's wrong with that ? How to install the last version of typescript ?

Comment: `0.9.7.0` WOW .. that is old :). Check your `PATH` environment variable, you probably have a path to the old compiler before the path to the `npm` global modules

Comment: Okay I finally uninstalled old versions through Add/Remove Programs. Thanks.